# Bad Design: Accessing near collection elements

Tags: c#, exception, collections

Once in a while I access a specific element in a list and need the previous and the following element.

However if the element i want to access is the last one in the collectioni would get an exception. Same with the other side.

To solve this i create this ugly if - else if - else statements.

```
        if ( i == this.Count() - 1 )
        {
             currToNext = new Vertice(this[i], this[0]);
             currToPrevious = new Vertice(this[i], this[i-1]);
        }
        else if ( i == 0 )
        {
             currToNext = new Vertice(this[i], this[i+1]);
             currToPrevious = new Vertice(this[i], this[this.Count() -1]);
        }
        else 
        {
             currToNext = new Vertice(this[i], this[i+1]);
             currToPrevious = new Vertice(this[i], this[i-1]);
        }
```

Is there any better way to solve this?

Comment: So if its last, next is first and if it's first previous is last? Is `this` a class that inherits from `List<T>`?

Comment: Why is that bad design? Its clear what you're trying to do. You could perhaps do it with less code, but that is the same design, and is probably *harder* to understand

Comment: I am not sure this question is best suited for Stack Overflow. You don't *really* have a problem you are trying to solve. Perhaps if you had more clear requirements on "what is better" then you could try asking on [codereview.se]

Comment: I think the main problem here is that you have to read the code to actually understand what the code **and question** is about. You're not mentioning that this is a **circular** collection, and that you pair the last element with the first and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. Use for the next

```
this[(i+1)%this.Count()]
```

And for the previous (credits to @Dmitry Bychenko)

```
this[(i -1 + this.Count)%this.Count()]
```

This way if your list has elements from 0 to 9 and you ask for element 9, you do do 10%10 = 0.

Comment: this only sovle the next

Comment: Oh sorry, this solves only the next. Updating including the previous.

Comment: `this[(i - 1 + this.Count)%this.Count]` for previous

Comment: Probably better to only call `Count()` once. Plus that way you could make it look nicer too